# AWS CloudFront Does not allow access to the site from other countries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

On my PC, I have access to the site and it lets me in. Literally everything works, and a redirect from `http` to `https`, and a redirect from `www` to `root`. But when I turn on the Germany VPN, for example, it does not let me into the site not on the root domain, not on `www`, the error is `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. (tried both USA and Romania - same result)

Deployed my NodeJS/React application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, got an SSL certificate, configured rules in the load balancer to redirect from `http` to `https`. In Route 53 from the records I have the following:
NS by default (already connected to Google Domains, where the domain itself was purchased) and SOA.
Manually registered record, type A, record name is `domain.com`, value/traffic route is an alias of my Elastic Beanstalk.

Redirection from `www.domain.com` to `domain.com` is also configured. I did it like this: I created an s3 bucket called `www.domain.com`, the region is where Elastic Beanstalk is located, unchecked "Block all public access" and created it. Then I activated the static hosting of the site, hosting type - Redirect requests to an object, host name - `domain.com`, protocol - `https`. I also made this bucket public permission by adding the following to the bucket policy:

```
{
         "Version": "2012-10-17",
         "Statement": [
           {
             "Sid": "PublicReadgetObject",
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Main": "*",
             "Action": "s3: GetObject",
             "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME/*"
           }
         ]
    }
```

Then I created a CloudFront distribution (since s3 does not work with the `https` protocol, as it is written in the official documentation), in the origin domain name I specify the endpoint of the Bucket site from the s3 basket, changed the Viewer protocol policy to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, chose my own ssl certificate, added an alternative domain name - `www.domain.com` and created it.

Then I go to Route 53, create an entry: Entry name - `www.domain.com` Type - value / routing traffic - CloudFront domain name alias. I save and wait (waited for a long time, 12 hours).

What am I doing wrong? I would be glad if you can help, because I have already run out of options

Comment: Did you accidently enable geographic restrictions in CloudFront? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html

Comment: Actually it sounds more like a DNS issue. Try checking your DNS record here: https://dnschecker.org/

Comment: Now I made an edit in one line of code, uploaded the updated version to Elastic Beanstalk, and for about 20 minutes even me is not allowed to the site, neither by root nor by www.

There are no geographic restrictions.

I looked at dnschecker.org, `domain.com` - crosses everywhere, `www.domain.com` - checkmarks everywhere.

What are my next steps?

Comment: I deleted my host zone on Route 53, created a new one, updated the name servers in Google Domains, I've been waiting for about an hour now, and the number of responses to `dnschecker.org` varies from 7 to 12. So far, when I try to get to the site via `domain.com` (I deleted the entry with the `www` redirect to `root`, deleted the s3 bucket, deleted the cloudfront) - it won't let me in. I don't understand what the problem is, it worked fine before. @MarkB